# Optimizer zero_grad() and optimize() - how to use when each sample split into patches?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset consisting of small RGB images. Each image is then split into a specific number of patches, each then being resized and blurred (Gaussian). The input of my model (see Thermal Image Enhancement using CNN (10.1109/IROS.2016.7759059), shallow 3-layers network for increasing the resolution and handling blurring issues in thermal images) is resized + blurred patch while the expected result is just the resized patch.

The network is rather simple:

```
class TEN_Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(TEN_Network, self).__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            ('conv1', nn.Conv2d(1, 64, 7, stride=1, padding=3)),
            ('relu1', nn.ReLU(True)),
            ('conv2', nn.Conv2d(64, 32, 5, stride=1, padding=2)),
            ('relu2', nn.ReLU(True)),
            ('conv3', nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)),
            ('relu3', nn.ReLU(True)),
            ('conv4', nn.Conv2d(32, 1, 3, stride=1, padding=1))
        ]))

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model(x)
        return x
```

I picked this CNN for numerous reasons simplicity being one of them. Since I am quite new to neural networks and PyTorch I thought it will provide a nice playground.

My question is this - given that each sample is split into patches should I zero the gradients (and respectively `step()` the optimizer) for each patch or should I calculate the average loss (sum of all losses for all patches in a sample divided by the number of patches) or should I run these two steps at the beginning of training my sample and after the patches have been processed (resulting in the above mentioned average loss per sample)?

Currently I have the following (pseudo-code, optimizer is Adam, loss is MSE):

```
# ...
for epoch_id in range(0, epochs_total):
    # Load dataset with dataloader
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=custom_dataset, ...)
    
    # Train
    for sample_expected, sample_input in next(iter(dataloader)):
        loss_sample_avg = 0.0
        patches_count = len(sample_expected)
        # optimizer.zero_grad() <---- HERE(1)

        for patch_expected, patch_input in zip(sample_expected, sample_input):
            # optimizer.zero_grad() <---- HERE(2)
            # ...

            patch_predicted = model(patch_input)
            loss = citerion(patch_predicted, patch_input)
            loss_sample_avg += loss.item()
            loss.backward()
            # optimizer.step() <---- HERE(2)?

        # optimizer.step() <---- HERE(1)


    # Validate
    ...
```

This is probably me not getting something very basic. I know that

- Optimizer `step()` should always be followed by a `zero_grad()`
- A `backward()` call is possible only after another `forward()` pass has been processed

Since the paper does not provide any code (tried reaching out to the authors but as expected nothing came out) I am trying to figure out how to implement it myself.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper? All the options you laid out can be valid, so unless there's some additional motivation then I would probably just run multiple experiments and choose the strategy that works best on the validation set.

Comment: @jodag Done, though it is IEEE. Alternative sources to get the contents of the paper are available of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass all patches as a batch. performing a gradient step on a sole patch consitutes pure stochastic gradient descent, which is generally not preferred because it yeilds a very noisy estimate of the desired gradient. Furthermore looping over each patch from the image is computationally inefficient.

At a minimum, batch all patches from one image together. Ideally though, you would pass multiple patches from multiple images as a batch. So `patch_input` and `patch_expected` should each be `[batch_size x color_channels x patch_height x path_width]` in size. `batch_size` should itself be the number of sampled patches per image times the number of images in a batch.

Likely, this will require very little modification of your code other than adding a few lines to *collate* the inputs and targets in their existing for into a single tensor each. I'd provide specifics but it isn't evident what form your targets and inputs take currently.